# jquery open only first button

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code that open pop on window that name of class is like my input value.
it works for my first part in html(PASS is first in my html ocde) but does not work for others.
what is the problem?

```
                </div>
            </div>  
<!---------------- POLL BUTTON DIV(POP-UP)---------------------->
            <div id="modal"  class="poll">
                <div id="content">

                </div>
            </div>  
<!---------------- PASS BUTTON DIV(POP-UP)---------------------->
            <div id="modal"  class="pass">
                <div id="content">

                </div>
            </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#link').click(function(e) { // Button which will activate our modal
            var block = $(this +":input").val();
                $('.'+block).reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
                    animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                    animationspeed: 600,                       // how fast animtions are
                    closeonbackgroundclick: true,              // if you click background will modal close?
                    dismissmodalclass: 'close'    // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
                });
            return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm not even sure how this is working as you are coercing a DOM element to a string and appending a jQuery psuedo selector to it...? Can you provide a working example of this in http://jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: **ID** Must be unique. Use **class** form multiple elements.

Answer (score 2):

Switch your `class` and `id` attributes on these and then call the class in jQuery, not the ID.

ID will only be referenced one time when traversing the DOM.  After that it stops searching.

Here is the correct way to structure with **HTML**:

```
        <div id="poll"  class="modal">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div id="pass"  class="modal">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also changed your `<div id="content">` to `<div class="content">` since you have more than one.  To select one in particular, use:

```
$('#pass').find('.content')
```

as an example.

Here is what you'll use to call in **jQuery**:

```
$('.modal').click()
```

this will replace your `$('#link').click()`